# Bootstrap 2.1.1 And Tooltips

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eMh4r/

Excuse me for being a novice, but I'm trying to get a tooltip working using bootstrap's front-end. I'm not really sure what's going on, and I would appreciate any help in getting the tooltip to work in the same way that it works on Bootstrap's website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following: http://jsfiddle.net/eMh4r/31/

I think one reason it didn't work in your fiddle was that you hadn't made the references to the bootstrap .js or .css. Also, your options should be passed as an object in the form .tooltip({"optionName" : "optionValue"});